# Windows transitions

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator and I got a quick question.
How can I choose the transition animation when opening a new window? I do not
want to use the default slide to right.

This is my code that I use (single context).

```
tab['tab1'].open(Window.Contacts());
```

This works in a way, but I would like it to open in the current tab.

```
Window.ContactsAvatars().open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your tabs group's name is `tab`.

Then, to force your transition style to the

`tab.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT})`

if it doesn't work, then try with the following snippet while calling the window to display :

```
tab.activeTab.open(contactsWindow,{animated:true,{transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
```